# Convert hex little endian String to int in java

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have hex in little endian format, i want to convert it to int, few examples:

"FC5F2E00" -> 3039228

"5E602E00" -> 3039326

```
String s1="FC5F2E00";
String s1="5E602E00";

    public int hexToInt(String hex){

}
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Do you have the hex string with you?

Comment: What code did you write?

Comment: You should update your question to provide some more information. You should provide your code samples, if you have done any. Without proper information, people might even vote to close your question.

Comment: @Swapnil The problem is how to create method that can do these conversion

Comment: @Craig.- The code is sample, two Strings.

Comment: @Saswat. - I am new in programming, so sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: @J.Davied Walk through every character, get the decimal equivalent value and add to your integer value.

Comment: @J.Davied, no problem brother. I was also new in SO once. And still today I make some silly mistakes. People here are ready to help us, but for that we also must provide them a proper information so that they can help us. :)

Comment: @Swapnil.- Thank you, but its wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to reverse the order of the hex-String and parse the String to an Integer. FC5F2E00 becomes 002E5FFC and 002E5FFC is 3039228.

```
public static int toLittleEndian(final String hex) {
    int ret = 0;
    String hexLittleEndian = "";
    if (hex.length() % 2 != 0) return ret;
    for (int i = hex.length() - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
        hexLittleEndian += hex.substring(i, i + 2);
    }
    ret = Integer.parseInt(hexLittleEndian, 16);
    return ret;
}

Input: FC5F2E00
Output: 3039228
```

Comment: Did it work also with `Long.parseLong` insted of `Integer.parseInt` ?