# Convert string of hex-encoded integers to int array in Java

Tags: java, string, integer, hex

For example, we have a string `"c4d2"`, known it is a `little`-endian coded 16-bit int `53956`. (It is NOT about conversion `"c4d2"` to `int[] {0xc4, 0xd2}`, but about coversion of `"c4d2"` to integer `53956`). How to convert the string to int use Java?

Use python I do

```
s = b'\xc4\xd2'
n = int.from_bytes(s, "little")
print(f"{s} -> {n}")
```

output is right

```
b'\xc4\xd2' -> 53956
```

Use Java I do

```
String s = "c4d2"; // 53956
byte[] b = HexFormat.of().parseHex(s);
int n = ByteBuffer.wrap(b).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort();
System.out.println(s + " -> " + Arrays.toString(b) + " -> " + n);
```

and got

```
c4d2 -> [-60, -46] -> -11580
```

that is wrong. But if I do conversion through binary string as

```
String s2 = Integer.toBinaryString(0xd2) + Integer.toBinaryString(0xc4);
int n2 = Integer.parseInt(s2, 2);
System.out.println(s + " -> " + s2 + " -> " + n2);
```

I got

```
c4d2 -> 1101001011000100 -> 53956
```

the result is right, but the method seems stange.

How to properly convert hex-string to int?

Comment: Your question title says you want to convert the hex-string to an `int []`.  But. in your example where you use `Integer.toBinaryString`, the end result is an `int`.  So, which is the desired result?

Comment: Java's short is signed, so its max value is 32767 and you got overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hex little endian String to int in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064861/convert-hex-little-endian-string-to-int-in-java)

Comment: In general, I want to convert a string which codes array of 16-bit integers (so, two bytes per int) to int array. But in example string "c4d2" shold be converted to int.

Comment: `int n = new BigInteger("c4d2", 16).intValue();`

Comment: Sorry, just realised you wanted little-endian, so `int n = ByteBuffer.wrap(new BigInteger(s, 16).toByteArray()).order(LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort(1) & 0xFFFF; // (import static of ByeOrder)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's short is signed, so its max value is 32767 and you got overflow. You can use `Short.toUnsignedInt()`:

```
    String s = "c4d2"; // 53956
    byte[] b = HexFormat.of().parseHex(s);
    int n = Short.toUnsignedInt(ByteBuffer.wrap(b).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort());
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + Arrays.toString(b) + " -> " + n);
```

prints

> c4d2 -> [-60, -46] -> 53956

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to reverse the values, and then use the *[Integer#parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,int))* method, specifying a *16* for the radix.

```java
String string = "c4d2";
StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder();
for (int index = string.length() - 1; index >= 0; index -= 2)
    reversed.append(string, index - 1, index + 1);
int number = Integer.parseInt(reversed.toString(), 16);
```

Output, for *number*.

```
53956
```